# React Native Popup Menu - Top Right styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base, react-native-popup-menu

[image: WhatsApp UI Clone]

Hi, I am trying to clone WhatsApp UI using NativeBase and react-navigation. I am using the `react-native-popup-menu` package and going on well except the fact that I want to adjust the width of the popup menu and I want the menu `top` and `right` to be 0.

Thanks.

Comment: how does your css look? it will be the first place i'll look at.